# set image height and width

Tags: java, android, imageview

How can I set a height and width of a imageView?
I doenst work with maxheight and maxwidth...

Here my code:

```
 <ImageView 
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:id="@+id/weatherIcon"
                 android:src="@drawable/weather_rain"
                 android:paddingLeft="39pt"
                 android:paddingTop="4pt"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
>
</ImageView>
```

will set width and height to 30 pixels.

Comment: If my understanding is correct you may want to use "30dip" instead.  sp or Scaled Pixels I thought was only for TextSize. I've not tried it this way though so I could be not entirely informed.

Comment: dp will take into account the device resolution.  sp won't.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html explains it all.